# Question - Praying (Christian)

Tags: salat, sunni

If an Islam friend I have is in trouble, as a Christian am I allowed to pray for them?

Thanks - O.C

Comment: I wonder if this question is on-topic here!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not even about Islam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can pray for them. Muslims and Christians are brothers and we both believe in the same 1 God. Prayers are always welcome. :)
Best,
Michelle

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The act of believing in a creator is virtuous. Same with the notion of believing that he is our sustainer and is worthy of thanksgiving.

For the most part we both worship The God. There are some details Christians and Muslims don't agree upon. Yet it doesn't make sense for one to believe to one whom he/she doesn't believe in, so praying The (Christian) God is totally acceptable in this case.

Comment: Mhm, thank you very much.